# Linear operator mapping Hilbert space to its subspace is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider a separable Hilbert space $H$ with orthogonal basis $\{e_{i}\}$ and a closed subspace $B=\overline{span(\gamma_{i},i\in\mathbb{N})}$, where $\gamma_{i}$ are linear independent vectors(which is not orthogonal) and $\gamma_{i}$ are bounded for all $i$. Now we define a linear map $T:H\rightarrow H$ by $Te_{i}=\gamma_{i}$, must $T$ a bounded mapping?

My thought is that if $||\gamma_{i}||$ is bounded for all $i$, that should be the case. But I can't give a concrete proof.

Comment: what are your thoughts?

Comment: Is there any reason why $\|\gamma_i\|$ is bounded?

Comment: Is $\{e_i\}_i$ a Schauder or Hamel basis?

Comment: @JacobManaker $\{e_{i}\}$ is Schauder basis

Comment: @JacobManaker: a Hamel basis cannot be orthogonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. The mapping $Te_n=e_1+e_n$ cannot be extended to a bounded linear operator, as $$T(e_1+e_2+\dots +e_n)=(n+1)e_1+e_2+\ldots +e_n$$ and $$\|e_1+e_2+\dots +e_n\|=\sqrt{n}$$ $$\|T(e_1+e_2+\dots +e_n)\|\ge n+1$$